# How do I get php5 running?

Tags: php, startup-applications

I have just installed php5 on Ubuntu, but it's not running.
How do I get it running?  Or more generally, how do I start an application software that doesn't have an entry in init.d?

Comment: Do you have apache up and running?

Comment: @Lnxslck yes... I disabled apache by default, and I have just got it running. Does this have an effect?

Answer (score 3):

If Apache is running (check by using a browser to go to apache address), then try this to see if php is running:

> vi /var/www/info.php

`<?php
phpinfo();?>`

Call that file in a browser (e.g. `http://ipapacheruns/info.php`), it could be (e.g. `http://localhost/info.php`):

Comment: +1 This is the best and easy way to test a successfully installed and running PHP.

Comment: Seems that there is something wrong with Apach2. I can't even open the index.html page from a web browser. I must did something wrong. I remember using the command `sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable 2` this day earlier... but I have enabled it, even restarted the system... :P

Comment: So what it looks like, is that your apache isn't running correctly, until you get the page showing the words "It works" or something like that, you won't be able to get php running.

Answer (score 0):

php5 runs as an Apache module, not by itself, so as long as  you have Apache running, it should be ready to process php scripts. You need to have libapache2-mod-php5 installed for this, and you may need to enable it with `sudo a2enmod php5`. When you restart apache, you can look in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and you should see something similar this:

```
[Sun Aug 05 06:33:46 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze13
 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
```

The PHP part tells you the module is ready to process php content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did exactly what you said, but it's still not running, even if apache2 is running well(with 6 processes). :P

Comment: Please check apache is running with a web browser

Comment: oops... seems not. Can't open the default page...

Comment: do you have any firewall software running? (ufw for instance).

Answer (score 0):

There are two main implementations of PHP: the Apache module (`libapache2-mod-php5`) and the terminal interpreter (`php5-cli`). The Apache module will cause Apache to check any files ending in .php for PHP script and run that script when a client requests that file. For this to happen, you need to install the package and request a PHP file through Apache.

The terminal interpreter is accessed by typing `php` into a terminal, and will allow you to type PHP directly (with a few modifications to handle linebreaks and execution).

PHP doesn't run as a window or anything like that. The phrasing of your question and your responses to others give me the impression that you don't what PHP is. It's a language, not a program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). I do know what PHP is, in order for _.php_ files to run, a php parser is needed, and here the parser is just the program version of PHP. I have previously installed several times the apache AND php packages separately, and they tend to work okay, I am not sure why it doesn't this time...